# drupal 7 triggers: email when a specific node type is viewed

Tags: drupal, triggers

I need to make Drupal 7 e-mail me (the admin, plain text is fine) every time a node type called MyType is viewed. I do NOT want an e-mail for any other node types. I would like to do this with minimal programming. drupal_mail requires a lot of programming it seems (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_system/7#comment-16454). Can I use Triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do this using triggers. Under Triggered rules (admin/rules/trigger), create a new rule with Event type="Content is going to be viewed". In Rule element, ad condition and select "Viewed Content" and select the content type. Add action and select "Send email to arbitrary email address" and give the recipient details. I hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks Aneesh. Are you using Triggers in Drupal 6 or 7? I can't find "Rule element" or "arbitrary email address" in Drupal 7.12 version. :-(